# ffmpeg video convert library on my VPS Linux based godaddy server not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have some query here for using your ffmpeg video convert library on my VPS Linux based godaddy server.

I have php 5.6.30 version on my server and I want to use your ffmpeg video convert library on my server so I can use that with 5.6.30 php version ?

As I have already many time try my self to install it but each time I am getting different errors while installing process so after that for installation of it on my server I have taken godaddy's support team help and paid them $100 for install ffmpeg on my VPS server then in end (after 12 days) they said me ffmpeg will work with older version of php only (they saying it will work until you will have php 4.0 after that with any latest version of php it will not work) so they said me downgrade your php version then only it will work, but I can't do that as I if I will do that then I will fetch some other issues in my project.

So here can you please confirm "your ffmpeg video convert library will work with my php version 5.6.30 (website hosted on godaddy's VPS Linux based server)" ?

if not working then please suggest me to best other similar library similar to ffmpeg  i want only two of the functionality 1) to cut the video 2)may be compress 3)Create thumb from the video.

Waiting for valuable response!

Comment: So here can you please confirm "your ffmpeg video convert library will work with my php version 5.6.30 (website hosted on godaddy's VPS Linux based server)" ?

Comment: Not knowing what exactly you refer to as `ffmpeg video convert library` it's hard to say. However if you know that then definitely you can check ther requirements of said library which should specify min. versions of required components. Then you can check what your VPS offers and you will know. If you are not technical then you may want to hire someone to do that for you if GD's support is not helpful

Comment: if any of the other alternative then please suggest me to best other similar library similar to ffmpeg i want only two of the functionality 1) to cut the video 2)may be compress 3)Create thumb from the video.

Comment: StackOverflow is **not** a tutorial site nor search engine replacement. We can help, but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on this in first place, including elementary **[research](https://google.com/)**.

Comment: i am using library PHP-FFMpeg-master and it's having error like Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Install dependencies to run test suite.'

Comment: then install it. you got install process documented here: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg Again if you are not technical then get someone to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PHP-FFmpeg changelog](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/CHANGELOG.mdhttp://), it was updated on 2016-03-08 to support PHP 7. Therefore Godaddy is incorrect in telling you that it will only work with versions older than 5.6.30. Your question was originally only about ffmpeg. Only in the comments do you mention PHP-ffmpeg. So I don't know if you really need to use PHP. If not, do you realize that ffmpeg is written in C (with some assembler routines)? You can build it for whatever system you have and call it from a bash shell if you want.